# Variable (enum?) holding one of two types in Swift 2

Tags: swift, enums

In a `UIViewController` subclass need to declare a variable called `webView` which can be of type `UIWebView` or `WKWebView` (depending on iOS version).

Is there a better way to do this (perhaps using an enum?) than one of these options:

1. Declaring the variable of type `UIView` and then conditionally casting to the two types every time I need to access it
2. Not declaring the variable in the common parent `UIViewController` super class, but declaring the variable of the specific type twice over in the two specific `UIViewController` subclasses? Feels like it violates the "Don't Repeat Yourself"/DRY principle.

Comment: I cannot test it currently, but what about `#if os (watchOS) typealias MyWebView = WKWebView #else typealias MyWebView = UIWebView #endif` ("build configuration statement") ?

Comment: I like this as an approach, but unfortunately I need a *runtime* solution and `#if`` & `typealias` appear to be compile time features and are therefore not available at runtime. Unless I've misunderstood something?

Comment: Yes, that is evaluated at compile. Actually I misunderstood the problem when reading your question on the phone yesterday. I thought you wanted to share code between and  iOS and watchOS app, which was quite stupid on my side.

Comment: What you could do is to define a *protocol* containing the required methods that you want to call on the view,  then make both UIWebView and WKWebView conform to that protocol (via categories) and declare the instance variable as `id<MyWebViewProtocol>`.

Comment: @MartinR - thanks - if you repost this as an answer, I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define a *protocol* containing the common methods that you want to call on the view:

```
protocol MyWebView {
    // ...
}
```

Then make both `UIWebView` and `WKWebView` conform to that protocol
(via extensions):

```
extension UIWebView : MyWebView {

}

@available(iOS 8.0, *)
extension WKWebView : MyWebView {

}
```

Now you can declare the instance variable as

```
var webView : MyWebView!
```

and initialize it depending on the iOS version:

```
if #available(iOS 8, *){
    webView = WKWebView()
} else {
    webView = UIWebView()
}
```

Comment: There seems to be a problem with this approach. The linker fails if the deployment target is iOS 7. I may have to delete the answer ...

Comment: You just need to weak link the WebKit framework to solve that :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in an app of mine, using a different deprecated framework. This solution worked for me:

Create a property as shown below:

```
var webView: AnyObject!
```

In `viewDidLoad`, initialize the web view using this code:

```
if #available(iOS 9, *){
    webView = WKWebView()
} else {
    webView = UIWebView()
}
```

Elsewhere in your code, when you need to do something with this web view, you need to do something similar:

```
if #available(iOS 9, *){
    let newWebView = webView as! WKWebView
    // use newWebView
} else {
    let oldWebView = webView as! UIWebView
    // use oldWebView
}
```

*Note*: Martin R's suggestion to use a type alias may work as well, but this solution I have tested myself.

Comment: Thanks - this is effectively what I was proposing with option 1. in the original post.

Definitely still open to other suggestions.